# AWS SNS SMS Local and International Pricing for India

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, sms, boto3, amazon-sns

I'm facing a pricing issue while using AWS SNS Text Messaging (SMS) Service in India. The [AWS SNS SMS Pricing Documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/sms-pricing/) says that the charge per SMS for '*All Networks*' is $0.00278 and for '*All Networks - International*' is $0.02171.
[image: AWS SNS SMS Pricing for India]

I need to send transactional messages such as Reminders and Alerts to each of our users. All the messages I send are very user-specific and hence I haven't created any topic.

The account information in the AWS SNS tab shows status as 'This account has production access in the Asia Pacific', and that I can send messages to any number.

Though I'm sending messages from region 'ap-south-1(Mumbai)' to Indian numbers only, the Cloudwatch logs say that the cost incurred per SMS is $0.02171 (*All Networks - International*).

What should I do differently to be billed the lesser '*All Networks*' price of $0.00278 per message?

I'm sending the messages to our users individually, with the following python3 code:

```
import boto3

sms_client= boto3.client("sns",
    aws_access_key_id="access_key",
    aws_secret_access_key="secret_access_key",
    region_name="ap-south-1")

numbers= "+917xxxxxxxx2"
message= "Message Contents"
response= sms_client.publish(
    PhoneNumber=numbers,
    Message=message,
    Subject="Reminder",
    MessageAttributes={
            'AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID': {
                'DataType': 'String',
                'StringValue': 'sender-1'
            },
            'AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType': {
                'DataType': 'String',
                'StringValue': 'Transactional'
            }})
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

By default, when you send messages to recipients in India, Amazon SNS uses International Long Distance Operator (ILDO) connections to transmit those messages. The price for sending messages using ILDO connections is higher than the price for sending messages through local routes. Currently, the price for sending ILDO messages is USD $0.02171 per message.

Check this AWS doc
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/channels-sms-senderid-india.html